# Как биндить Generic VM?

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток.
Есть interface базовой ViewModel:

```
interface IBaseViewModel<T>
{
  ICommand AddCommand { get; }

  ICommand<T> EditCommand { get; }

  ICommand<T> DeleteCommand { get; }
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать биндинг через этот интерфейс, а не получается:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=(vm:IBaseViewModel`1.AddCommand)}"/> 

<Button Command="{Binding Path=(vm:IBaseViewModel`1.EditCommand)}"/>
```

Первая кнопка - всё ок (правда во время работы выкидывает ошибку: Непредвиденный символ "`" в строке "vm:IBaseViewModel`1"), вторая кидает ошибку:
[image: ошибка]

Comment: А если конкретную реализацию указать в <> ?

Comment: А разве xaml умеет работать с привязкой к обобщенным типам? Сдается мне, что нет, не может. Да, и странно это, вам что, какой-то динамический полиморфизм потребен во вьюшке? Зачем это все?

Comment: @iluxa1810 не работает, первая мысль такая была уже

Comment: А зачем вы тип указываете? Разве он должен указываться при привязке?

Comment: @iluxa1810 первый комментарий не так понял, возможно.
Если наследовать интерфейс в классе и привязываться конкретно к классу, то никаких проблем нет. Суть в том, что есть "шаблон", в котором не известно ничего про будущую ViewModel, поэтому нужно как-то через интерфейс забиндиться

Comment: А если сделать базовый интерфейс с ICommand без generic, а IInterface<T> наследовать от него с указанием new для ICommand<T>. Ну и [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/generics) написано в доках, как generic использовать в XAML, может поможет